# Story about a rainstorm that only the blind can see

Tags: story-identification

I would have read this some time probably in the early 1990s. I don't remember how old it was at the time.

I only remember the beginning, and a snatch of details from it:

- Several blind characters
- One of the blind characters told his mother to take her umbrella with her, because it was raining. She looked but didn't see any rain.
- One blind boy, possibly named Chris or similar, described the rain as being of different colours; he described the colours in terms of emotion. He described one colour as 'looking like when you feel angry', which his mother interpreted as red.
- I think the other blind characters also saw the rain, but I can't remember enough detail to be sure.
- The mother did go outside, but took her umbrella. I think there were a few people carrying umbrellas, but not everyone. After she got back, the mother saw small holes all over the umbrella.

I don't remember the author, but I think it was an oldish book at the time. I don't remember if it was a novel or part of a short story collection.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about this story is scifi or fantasy?

Comment: @Valorum I think an invisible rainstorm that blind people can see qualifies somewhere between science fiction and fantasy, depending on why it's happening...

Comment: @Paul - It reads like the blind person is fantasising, which doesn't make it a fantasy, any more than Scrubs or Ally McBeal are *fantasies*.

Comment: @Valorum An invisible rain that blind people can see and ascribe colours to, *which leaves holes in umbrellas*, is not the blind person fantasizing.

Comment: @Werrf - You didn't say that it was the *invisible rain* that made the holes in the umbrella. Also, what happened to the people who weren't carrying umbrellas?

Comment: @Valorum I don't remember enough of the book to say for certain that it was the rain that made the holes in the umbrellas; I also don't remember what happened to everyone else. That's why I'm looking for the book. Sci-fi is the closest match I can find for it. How is nitpicking productive?

Comment: @Werrf - I'm trying to gauge whether this question is an appropriate fit for the site. If it's not about scifi or fantasy, the community wastes its collective time.

Comment: @Valorum I don't see that there's any way to gauge that with almost *any* story identification question unless we find a match, and I can't see anything in my description that would suggest it was not sci-fi or fantasy. As best I can remember, the story was sci-fi; there was a vague implication, which I cannot describe in enough detail to be helpful, that the rain was coming from space. It was *not* all in the boy's imagination, or if it was it wasn't even implied in the part that I can remember.

Comment: @Werrf - In which case, you definitely need to edit that into the question.

Comment: There does not seem to be anything in this question that would lead one to believe that the characters involved were fantasizing. Couldn't we suppose this to  be the case for a lot of short story identifications?

Comment: Did the child pursuade his mother the rain was a threat and get them drinking orange juice to stay away from the influence the rain was having? It rings a vague bell if so.

Comment: It was part of a short story collection. Also in the same book was a story about a guy and his typewriter during a machine uprising.

Comment: I have read the story and the collection -also in about the 1990s and that story did stick in my memory but can't find out what it was. Think it was a collection aimed at teenagers in the local library.

Comment: The story "about a guy and his typewriter during a machine uprising" sounds a lot like "Skirmish" by Clifford Simak. Can you remember anything else about any stories in the same collection?

Comment: I don't understand. What good were the umbrellas if the raindrops were making holes in them? Why didn't the mother feel the raindrops that were coming through the umbrella? What happened to the people who were out in the rain without umbrellas?

Comment: synesthesia is the name of the phenomenona where the senses get cross wired and the subject sees sounds and hears colors and so on.  In case it helps someone.   
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia_in_fiction